# Android Ogre3D Error Linux

Tags: android, linux, ogre3d

I am running into a problem when I am trying to build my project. I am coming across this error message:

```
Android/ogre/build/SampleBrowserNDK/assets/materials/scripts/IsoSurf.material: error: File is case-insensitive equivalent to: Android/ogre/build/SampleBrowserNDK/assets/materials/scripts/Isosurf.material
```

Comment: I assume that material file is not present twice in the same folder right? At least on Windows that is impossible, but I am not sure about other operating systems...

Comment: Thnak you i some how did have two different files in there IsoSurf and Isosurf

Comment: So the issue is solved?

Comment: Yes the issue is solved thank you very much

Comment: Then please post an answer and mark it as correct to close this thread. Or I will ;) ...